# How to recover my app source code from APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, decompiler

I created a simple APK for a science fair project and as my computer updated I completely lost my source code. Luckily I still have the apk.

However, I cannot find a way to get the source code from the apk file.
I did my research and tried to use a decompiler to get the source code and it didn't work.
Is there anybody that can help with this?
If it is not possible, is there a way to change my apk file to an aab file so I can upload it to google play store?

If it is not possible, is there a way to change my apk file to an aab file so I can upload it to google play store?

Comment: You can try to recover your self-written classes uses [Jadx-Gui](https://github.com/skylot/jadx). Create a new AS project and re-create your classes using the code shown in Jadx.

Comment: I think it can be answer for your question? [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)